# How do I change my review vote?

Tags: support, review, voting

I selected the wrong button when reviewing [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/review/close/45237).  I did not see a way to undo my mistake.

Is this possible?

Comment: I believe it is possible to go to the question which you voted to close, click "close" and reverse your vote.  I am uncertain for how long this is possible.